# Custom callBack on a Modal with conditional rendering

Tags: callback, react-native, conditional-rendering, react-native-modal

I am building a ride sharing app to learn react-native. In order to publish a new Ride, I have a `Modal` which renders conditionaly on the `step` state and each step has a diferente UI. Like:

```
let screen;
if (step===1){
        ecraStep=<Screen1/>
} if (step===2){
        ecraStep=<Screen2/>
} ...
```

On `step=1` (which is the initial value) I want the callBack button to close the `Modal` and whenever step>1 I want it to call the following function:

```
function togglePreviousStep() {
   setStep(step-1);
};
```

Which is essentially going back to the last rendered screen. I have tried it by writting this inside the `Modal` function component:

```
useFocusEffect(
        React.useCallback(() => {
          const onBackPress = () => {
            if (step>1) {
              togglePreviousStep();
              return true;
            } else if (step===1) {
                props.closeModal();
              return false;
            }
          };
          BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress);
          return () =>
            BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress);
        }, [step, togglePreviousStep])
      );
```

However, no matter the `step` state, whenever I press the backButton it closes the `Modal`. I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

****EDITED****

I implemented the `Modal` from `react-native-modal`. I used the prop `onBackButtonPress` like this:

```
<Modal 
        onBackButtonPress={props.onBackButtonPress} 
        visible={showModal} 
        //...
        >
                    <NewRidesModal
                        //...
                        />
                </Modal>
```

And inside the Modal Screen I wrote:

```
if (step===1) {
        onBackPressButton=(() => props.closeModal());
    } else if (step>1){
        onBackPressButton=(() => togglePreviousStep())
    }
```

However, it still closes the modal when I press the android back button...

Comment: If you are using react native modal it have a prop onBackButtonPress when you should put your logic instead of use that listener try to move to it and update us.

Comment: Yes I do have a native Modal. So I can just pass the onBackButtonPress as prop to a function that contains the logic of my listeners?

Comment: This package got that prop https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal, modal from RN miss alot of features.

Comment: Could you read the edit please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onBackBackButtonPress is actually deprecated or removed.

Later on, I read a bit more about the modal documents on https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal#onrequestclose and I found out that:

> The onRequestClose callback is called when the user taps the hardware
> back button on Android or the menu button on Apple TV.

I should have investigated this before making this question. All I needed can be done with the `onRequestClose` prop like the following:

```
<Modal 
    onRequestClose={() => {
      if (step===1) {
        toggleModal();
    } else if (step>1 && step<8){
        togglePreviousStep(); 
    }
    }}
>
    //...
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. If not put all your code involved because the split piece of them is hard to connect what are you doing.

```
<Modal 
        onBackButtonPress={() => {
        if (step===1) {
         props.closeModal();
        } else if (step>1){
          togglePreviousStep()
        }

        }} 
        visible={showModal} 
        //...
        >
                    <NewRidesModal
                        //...
                        />
                </Modal>
```

Comment: I just noticed that even when I use the console.log in the onBackButtonPress prop it doesn't even return anything. ( onBackButtonPress={() => console.log('Something')} )

Comment: Is the prop somehow deprecated?

Comment: Well how isn't it returning nothing then?

Comment: you comment your back listener ?

Comment: onBackButtonPress={() => console.log('Something')}